# Python usbmount checking for device before writing

Tags: python, usb, debian

I'm using debian with usbmount. I want to check if a USB memory stick is available to write to.

Currently I check if a specific dir exists on the USB drive. If this is True I can then write the rest of my files - `os.path.isdir('/media/usb0/Test_Folder')`

I would like to create Test_Folder if it doesn't exist. However `/media/usb0/` exists even if no USB device is there so I can't just  `os.mkdir('/media/usb0/Test_Folder')` As it makes the file locally.

I need a check that there is a usb drive available on `/media/usb0/` to write to before creating the file. Is there a quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat /etc/mtab | awk '{ print $2 }'`
Will give you a list of mountpoints. You can as well read /etc/mtab yourself and just check if anything's mounted under /media/usb0 (file format: whitespace-divided, most likely single space). The second column is mount destination, the first is the source.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing as you said checking /etc/mtab

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this answer, I used this to make this script to backup a beagle bone black image to usb-drive , but only when one was available:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
if cat /etc/mtab | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep usb
then
 echo "usb attached"
 echo "backing up to usb"
 dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 | pv -s 4G -peta | gzip -1 > /media/usb0/bb_backup.img.gz
else
 echo "no usb drive inserted"
fi
```

Comment: the `cat /etc/mtab | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep usb` line seems to snag USB drives that are no longer plugged in bc they weren't unmounted.  Anyway to make this solution more robust for those cases (ie headless system w/ no keyboard)